# Select tag that has input enable attribute

Tags: html, select, html-select

I have a page that the user can submit news.the users able to select the `news group`  from the drop down list as you can see here :

```
   <select class="form-control" name="NewsGroup" id="NewsGroup">

                                    @foreach (string Group in ViewBag.NewsGroup)
                                    {
                                        <option value="@Group">@Group</option>
                                    }
                                </select>
```

The problem is if the group doesn't exist in the drop down list the user should be able to enter the new group .but the `select` tag doesn't have any option that the user can enter the new value and the user have to select from the list .
how can add this option to the `drop down list`?

Comment: Just check the number of your options and if there is no options, echo an input.

Comment: @VladimirSerykh You are right ,but i need if the group doesn't exist in the list the user should be able to enter in too.so i need in both situations

Comment: You could not do this using plain html select. Find special JQuery plugin for that or write JS logic by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use only a select for this purpose.

One solution could be to add an option named "other", and below add an input text where the user can enter what he wants. Optionality, you can show the text input only when the option "other" is selected.